# Ansible playbook with some tasks meant for control server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

I am getting stuck on this playbook where I have a desire to combine some tasks to run locally on the control machine, while other tasks run on the target inventory hosts.  I have tried several different methods but still cannot get it working.

When I run the playbook, it seems like Ansible is not working with the localhost on the task where `local_action:` is configured.  In this task I simply want to validate whether the file exists or not on the control server, but more importantly, I will want to add a task that does a `curl` command to fetch the RPM file and save it to the control server. I have not written this task yet because I cannot even get the `stat` module to work on the control server.  One problem I think I have is that I am trying to use inventory variables of the target inventory group with the task that is meant to run on the control server only.  What else am I doing wrong?

This is the error I am getting:

```
TASK [check to see if the RPM already exists in the bucket mount] **************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.10.188.70]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

Playbook code:

```
---
- name: install gcsfuse
  hosts: "{{ targets }}"
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  become_user: root

  tasks:
    - name: get current dnr version of gfuse
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: dnf list installed | grep gcsfuse
      register: dnr_fuse_version

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dnr_fuse_version.stdout }}"

    - name: get current rpm fuse versions 
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: rpm -qa | grep fuse
      register: rpm_fuse_version

    - name: check to see if the RPM already exists in the bucket mount
      local_action:
        module: ansible.builtin.stat
        path: "{{ software }}/gcsfuse-{{ gfuse_version }}-1.x86_64.rpm"
      run_once: true
      register: file_stat

    - debug:
        var: file_stat.stat.exists
```

Comment: I should note that the "10.10.188.70" in the error msg is one of the target hosts in the inventory --leading me to believe that I am not connecting to the localhost in this particular task.

Comment: The error is `sudo: a password is required`. Are you able to `sudo` without a password on the local system? Unrelated to your question, consider using [`delegate_to: localhost`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) rather than `local_action` because it doesn't require you to to change the syntax of your task (i.e., replacing the module name with the `module:` keyword).

Comment: yes, you are correct, I finally figured that out, just now. Code posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this figured out, I broke it out into two host groups and also removed the `become` requirement for the curl command, as my ansible user already has root privileges on the control node.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Get stats of a file
      ansible.builtin.stat:
        path: "{{ software }}/gcsfuse-{{ gfuse_version }}-1.x86_64.rpm"
      register: file_stat
    - debug:
        var: file_stat.stat.exists

    - name: change to software directory 
      ansible.builtin.shell: cd "{{ software }}"
      when: not file_stat.stat.exists

    - name: download RPM file if absent 
      ansible.builtin.command: "curl -v -O -L https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/releases/download/v{{ gfuse_version }}/gcsfuse-{{ gfuse_version }}-1.x86_64.rpm"
      # become: yes
      when: not file_stat.stat.exists

- hosts: "{{ targets }}"
  tasks:
    - name: get current dnr version of gfuse
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: dnf list installed | grep gcsfuse
      register: dnr_fuse_version

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dnr_fuse_version.stdout }}"

    - name: get current rpm fuse versions
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: rpm -qa | grep fuse
      register: rpm_fuse_version

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ rpm_fuse_version.stdout_lines }}"
```